# How to deal with zombie processes whose threads are still running

Tags: python, linux, cudnn, zombie-process

I was training a deep learning model, but an exception related to cuDNN occurred. I wanted to terminate the process through `kill -9 PID`, but found that the process status changed to Zombie. It may be that the thread [cuda-EvtHandlr] in the zombie process is still running, so the process cannot be recycled by init(PID:1)? How should I handle this besides rebooting?

[image]

I've tried sending a SIGCHLD signal to the init process but that doesn't work :(
[image]

Comment: If the parent process dies before reading the child's exit status, the child remains a zombie. Usually the system will terminate the zombie after a while.

Comment: 12 hours later, the zombie process still exists and the [cuda-EvtHandlr] thread keeps running. Finally the problem was solved by restarting the system :(